# Conceptual reason behind Shimura lifts

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, half-integral-weight

Shimura lifts are correspondence between integer weight and half-integral weight automorphic forms. Half integral weight things are associated to representation of a double cover of $G =SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, where as integer things live already in a rep of $G$.

> Q: Is there a conceptual (representation-theoretic) explanation for this phenomenon? Is there a local (in terms of places) analogue of this phenomenon?

Comment: Yes, this comes from the pair $SO(2,1)\times Mp(2)$ inside Mp(6)$, both globally/automorphically and locally.

Comment: What phenomenon exactly? Are you talking about the Shimura correspondence?

Comment: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Shimura_correspondence

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimura_correspondence